# How to use pugixml in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, pugixml

I have never added a library to Dev-C++. I read the guide [here](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html#quickstart.main.loading).

So I added two lines of code to my cpp file:

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"
#include "pugiconfig.hpp"
```

But I get errors like this:

```
[Linker error] C:\Users\MATRIX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYfRAuS.o:2.visualizza tutto.cpp:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `pugi::xml_document::xml_document()'
```

Can someone tell me how to do this in Dev-C++? I need to create a simple program that reads the XML that I created.

Comment: What's your problem? There's no difference between devc++ or any other c++ editor/ide/compiler with respect to include syntax. Have you forgotten #s?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov It's a linker error, meaning that there's no problem with the syntax. Linking is done after the syntax check. It usually means you forgot to write the implementation of a function or misspelled its header, or your compiler doesn't know where the implementation is (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `pugixml` libraries.  In Dev-C++ go to your project's linker settings and find the pugixml `.lib` files and add them.

Comment: To expand: In general, with outside libraries, there are header files (declaring things) and there is object (not C++ objects) code (defining those things). Since the same header file can have different implementations, you have to point Dev-C++ to the compiled code.

Comment: There is no pugixml .lib in the pugixml zip file. I have .hpp and .cpp files

Comment: You probably need to compile the library.  Alternatively, you can try to find a pre-compiled version of it.

Comment: Do you know where I can find even other precompiled library for xml parsing? I need to create an exe application ( DOS style graphic) which show the content of an xml file. Not the tags only the content and I need to add a description for the information in every tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .lib file, you need to add `pugixml.cpp` to compilation.
In Dev-C++ menu choose "Project" - > "Add To Project..." and choose `pugixml.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the existing files' path to the include directory, then add the existing files to your project.

Then you will be able to reference them in `#include` and also in written code.